# video in sequence from array cannot be played

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, video

***functionality:***

A video from a list of videos will be played when a user touches a `<button>`. After the video has finished playing, a 3rd page will `fadeIn()`. And after a delay of 5s, the entire program will perform a refresh via `location.reload();`. After which, another 1 video from a list of video will be played again when a user touches a `<button>` and the entire loop repeats again.

videos that is played will be following the sequence as stated within the array declared

```
var videolist=["video#3", "video#2", "video#1", "video#4"];
```

hence, the flow is:

1. when user clicks on a
2. plays 1st video (video#3) from videolist array
3. at the end of video(video#3), videoIndex will increment and after a delay of 3s, program refreshes.
4. user repeats step 1, however, the 2nd video (video#2) from the array will play instead of the 1st video that was played.

***What I have done:***

I have done a start() that will play the video from the videoarray and increment each videoIndex at the end of the each video that is played.

Code:

```js
var videoList = ["lib/video/A.mp4", "lib/video/B.mp4", "lib/video/C.mp4", "lib/video/D.mp4", "lib/video/E.mp4", "lib/video/F.mp4", ];
var videoIndex = 0;
var video_increment = [];


function StartTest() {

  $('#C_Main').fadeOut();
  //play fixed sequence "random" video
  $('#Chl_Selection').fadeIn();

  $("#Chl_Selection_Video").jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
      //console.log("currentPlaying " + videoList[videoIndex]);
      $("#Chl_Selection_Video").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4v: videoList[videoIndex]
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    ended: function() {
      //after video has played, increment the videoIndex
      videoIndex++;
      if (videoIndex >= videoList.length) {
        //console.log("Next" + videoIndex);
        videoIndex = 0;
      }
      console.log("videoIndex" + videoIndex);

      //push value of videoIndex into empty array for temporary store.
      video_increment.push(videoIndex);
      //set local storage
      localStorage.setItem("video_increment", video_increment);

      //Display Thank you page
      $('#Chl_Selection').fadeOut();
      $('#Chl_ThankYou').fadeIn(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload();
        }, 5000);
      });
    },
    swfPath: "javascript",
    muted: true,
    loop: true,
    supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
    size: {
      width: 1080,
      height: 1920
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.Test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1080px;
  height: 1740px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

<div id="C_Main" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=1; top:0px; left:0px;">

  <button class="Test" onclick="StartTest()"></button>

  <div id="Chl_Selection" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=2; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">

    <!--Video Div-->
    <div id="Chl_Selection_Video" style="position:absolute;"></div>

  </div>

  <div id="Chl_ThankYou" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">

    <!-- TEST IMAGE -->

    <img id="ThankYou" src="lib/img/Chl_ThankYou.png" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width: 1080px; height:1920px;" />

  </div>
```

***Issue:***

At this point, I am able to show that the videoIndex increment after the initial video is played. However, I am not able to display the next video when the entire program refreshes. It will still be displaying the first video from the array list that is played.
I have also tried on using `localStorage.setItem("video_increment", video_increment);`

Hence, I would like to ask for help, in what am I missing from my existing code.

Comment: Your problem lies on the call to `location.reload()` inside the thank you fadeIn callback. It will reload the page therefore all your variables reset as well. You need to find another way to play the current video rather than refreshing the page.

Comment: Another thing, you can actually use `localStorage` for this, but then you need to retrieve the last saved value at the start of your program, like `var video_increment = localStorage.getItem('video_increment')`. But careful though, non-primitive values are serialized when stored in `localStorage`. I recommend saving there simply the index for the next video, so you can retrieve it afterwards and use it directly.

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz, is there any other way to reference the variable when i call on location.reload()?? I have read about caching the variables when doing a location.reload().

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz, I have actually tried to use localStorage but it is not working. I have actually included that in my code. Please have a look

Comment: Read my second comment. You can use it but you need to retrieve the value, otherwise there's no point in storing it ;)

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz I have actually tried to retrieve that value at document,getready. however when i do a console.log. There is no value at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121547/discussion-between-oscar-gomez-alcaniz-and-luke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code to actually use the `localStorage` in order not to lose the current index after reload:

```
var videoList = ["lib/video/A.mp4", "lib/video/B.mp4", "lib/video/C.mp4", "lib/video/D.mp4", "lib/video/E.mp4", "lib/video/F.mp4", ];
// Retrieve last index from localStorage. We parse it to integer, 
// since values are serialized in strings when stored in localStorage
var videoIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('currentIndex')) || 0;

function StartTest() {
  $('#C_Main').fadeOut();
  //play fixed sequence "random" video
  $('#Chl_Selection').fadeIn();

  $("#Chl_Selection_Video").jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
      //console.log("currentPlaying " + videoList[videoIndex]);
      $("#Chl_Selection_Video").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4v: videoList[videoIndex]
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    ended: function() {
      //after video has played, increment the videoIndex
      videoIndex++;
      if (videoIndex >= videoList.length) {
        //console.log("Next" + videoIndex);
        videoIndex = 0;
      }
      console.log("videoIndex" + videoIndex);

      //set local storage
      localStorage.setItem("currentIndex", videoIndex);

      //Display Thank you page
      $('#Chl_Selection').fadeOut();
      $('#Chl_ThankYou').fadeIn(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload();
        }, 5000);
      });
    },
    swfPath: "javascript",
    muted: true,
    loop: true,
    supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
    size: {
      width: 1080,
      height: 1920
    }
  });
}
```